# Foreign key is null (while it is not) when using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I am using

```
var s = db.sModels.ToList().First(r => r.Status == CustomStatus.Available);
```

to fetch the first available item.

However, when fetched, a foreign key in `s` turns out to be `null`.

I have connected to the database and saw that the foreign key is not `null` (but is `1`).

Why does it become `null`?

Comment: Why are you calling `.ToList()` before `First`?  It's probably not the source of your problem, but it's a wasted effort.

Comment: @Tim S. Because otherwise there will be a not-supported exception. (The specified type member 'Status' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming this is Linq to Entities - that is the default  behavior - if you want to materialize the related entity - let's say `SomeEntity` you can use an `Include` query in which case the FK and entity will be populated:

```
var s = db.sModels.Include(r=> r.SomeEntity)
                  .First(r => r.Status == CustomStatus.Available);
```

For a workaround w/o using an Include query to just retrieve the FKs see this blog post: ["Getting Foreign Key Values with Linq-to-Entities"](http://naspinski.net/post/Getting-Foreign-Key-Values-with-Linq-to-Entities.aspx)

As noted in a comment to the question Linq to Entities does not support enums right now hence above would actually not work as is. As a workaround (until EF 5) you can use integers on the DB for now:

```
int statusAvailable = (int) CustomStatus.Available;
var s = db.sModels.Include(r=> r.SomeEntity)
                  .First(r => r.Status == statusAvailable);
```

Comment: Magical! Would you mind to further tell me why the foreign key is `null` by default?

Comment: Just a design decision of the EF team I suppose - Also EF 5 will provide support for enum's so you shouldn't need your workaround with `ToList()` - which will be a performance drag. Until then I would use integer values on the DB instead of materializing *all* results.